# Responsive search box issue, need help please

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently, I use PrestaShop, and I wanted to change the width of search box, but, when I change the width of search box to 650px, on desktop it's ok, but on mobile the search box is very long — not responsive at all. Can you help with this issue please?

```css
#search_block_top {
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
}
#search_block_top #searchbox {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
#search_block_top .btn.button-search {
  background: #7ab55c;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 11px 0;
}
#search_block_top .btn.button-search span {
  display: none;
}
#search_block_top .btn.button-search:before {
  content: "\f002";
  display: block;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#search_block_top .btn.button-search:hover {
  color: #6f6f6f;
}
#search_block_top #search_query_top {
  display: inline;
  padding: 13px 60px 13px 13px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.ac_results {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d6d4d4;
  width: 271px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.ac_results li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #686666;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
.ac_results li.ac_odd {
  background: #fff;
}
.ac_results li:hover,
.ac_results li.ac_over {
  background: #fbfbfb;
}
form#searchbox {
  position: relative;
}
form#searchbox label {
  color: #333;
}
form#searchbox input#search_query_block {
  margin-right: 10px;
  max-width: 222px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
form#searchbox .button.button-small {
  float: left;
}
form#searchbox .button.button-small i {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1ccd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting max-width

```
#search_block_top {
 padding-top: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 650px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use media queries and write something like that:

```
#search_block_top {
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 650px;
  @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    width: 95%;
  }

}
```